# UnmarshalException - Namespace Issue?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I get the following exception when I attempt to unmarshall XML back into java code. It seems like I am missing the namespace declaration somewhere, but I am not sure where.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"wg_provider").
Expected elements are <{http://www.warriorgateway.org/WGProvider.xsd}wg_provider>
```

This file was originally created with a JAXB marshaller here:

```
    JAXBContext providerContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(WgProvider.class);
    Marshaller providerMarshaller = providerContext.createMarshaller();
    providerMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    StringWriter providerWriter = new StringWriter();
    providerMarshaller.marshal(provider, providerWriter);
```

Here is the top of the Schema file:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.warriorgateway.org/WGProvider.xsd"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.warriorgateway.org/WGProvider.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="wg_provider">
        <xsd:complexType>
```

Here is the the top of the XML file to be unmarshalled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wg_provider xmlns="http://www.warriorgateway.org/WGProvider.xsd">
    <ein>26-0081701</ein>
    <name>MOMS CLUB</name>
    <is_virtual>false</is_virtual>
    <description>
</description>
```

Here is the top of the JAXB generated Java file:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "wg_provider" )
public class WgProvider {
```

I tried adding the namespace element to the Annotation but it made no difference.

Here is the package-info.xml content:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.warriorgateway.org/WGProvider.xsd", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.warriorgateway.api.model.wg;
```

And finally here is the unmarshalling code:

```
for (String wrappedProviderXML : wrappedProviderXMLList) {

    DocumentBuilderFactory documentbuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentbuilder = documentbuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    ByteArrayInputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wrappedProviderXML.getBytes());
    Document providerXMLDocument = documentbuilder.parse(xmlStream);

    JAXBContext wgProviderContext;
    try {
        wgProviderContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(WgProvider.class);
        Unmarshaller wgProviderUnmarshaller = wgProviderContext.createUnmarshaller();

        WgProvider wgProvider = (WgProvider) wgProviderUnmarshaller.unmarshal(providerXMLDocument);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Thanks-in-advance,

Guido

P.S. I am using Netbeans 7 to generate the bindings.

Comment: You may find the following useful: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - I put up some more info above. Are you thinking that I need to add a "NamespacePrefixMapper?"

Comment: You do not need to use `NamespacePrefixMapper`.  It appears as though your input document is not namespace qualified.  What does your unmarshal code look like?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - Thanks Blaise. Is there a setting to make Java generate a namespace qualified document? Or is this something I am missing in the Schema file? I am a recent convert to the XML world so I may have done something boneheaded.

Comment: I have added an answer with the necessary details:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8915769/383861

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sample you need to set your `DocumentBuilderFactory` to be namespace aware:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentbuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentbuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

You could also unmarshal the `ByteArrayInputStream` directly:

```
unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStream);
```